# Scala Play Future[Response] always empty

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, future

The `Future[Response].value`: `Option[Try[Response]]` is always empty. Am I misunderstanding Futures? Do I need to wrap this in an `onSuccess`? But then it won't return a String, but a Unit?

```
@tailrec private def initConnection: String =
  {
    val response: Future[Response] = initHeaders(WS.url(url)).post(authBody)
    val retry: Boolean = {
      response.value.isEmpty || response.value.get.isFailure || response.value.get.get.header("ConnectionID").isEmpty
    }

    if (!retry) return response.value.get.get.header("ConnectionID").get
    else initConnection
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Future#value`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@value:Option[Try[T]]) does not block on the future. If the future is already completed at the time of calling `value`, you will get `Some(_)`, otherwise it will be `None`. So you see only `None` since you check the `value` immediately after sending the request and it hasn't finished yet. You can use future combinators like `collect` and `recoverWith` to implement the retry functionality and return a `Future[String]` instead of a `String`. If you really need the value later, you will have to `Await.result` the future.

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.concurrent.Await

private def initConnectionFuture: Future[String] =
  initHeaders(WS.url(url)).post(authBody).collect {
    case response if response.header("ConnectionID").isDefined =>
      response.header("ConnectionID").get
  }.recoverWith {
    case NonFatal(_) => initConnectionFuture
  }

private def initConnection: String =
  Await.result(initConnectionFuture, 5 seconds) // or any other acceptable timeout
```

In addition to the timeout, you might also want to limit the number of retries, e.g.

```
private def initConnectionFuture(retries: Int = 5): Future[String] =
  initHeaders(WS.url(url)).post(authBody).collect {
    case response if response.header("ConnectionID").isDefined =>
      response.header("ConnectionID").get
  }.recoverWith {
    case NonFatal(_) if retries > 0 => initConnectionFuture(retries - 1)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would execute asynchronously until the value was needed, at which point it would automatically block.

Comment: Is the following statement correct? "The concurrency optimizations done on Future is done during compile time. My earlier assumption would require run-time optimization."

Comment: Per design, no method on Future will ever block. The only call that blocks is `Await.result` and this is not defined on Future.

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler optimizations that are special to Future.

Comment: why is @tailrec removed when using recoverWith? (even the compiler suggests that I remove the annotation) If I don't limit the number of retries, don't we have potential stack overflow on infinite recursion? Does Scala auto-optimize to reuse the stack on recoverWith? Or does it not optimize, thus requiring a limit on the number of retries?

Comment: The tail-call is `recoverWith`, not the method itself, so it's no longer a tail-recursive method. The method finishes immediately after `recoverWith` (it does not directly call itself and consumes stack) and those recursive invocations will likely be running on different threads; typical stack-safety reasoning doesn't apply here.